# AWS - S3 get objects from bucket->folder PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2

i am new for the AWS S3. i wanted to know the best way to retrieve data from the AWS with `bucket -> folder -> objects`

i am using with PHP sdk. i have downloaded SDK from the AWS but its not working fine. or i may be wrong with the steps. can anyone suggest me the best sdk ready-made that i can use for AWS S3.

in functionality that i am developing the hierarchy level as below

```
-> Bucket
  -> Folder 1 (video)
       -> objects (all video file here)
  -> Folder 2 (video)
       -> objects (all video file here)
  -> Folder 3 (image)
       -> objects (all image file here)
```

i want to know all download, upload and delete objects from `bucket->folders`

Comment: `but its not working fine` Please mention what's not working fine.

Comment: @Alok i am getting blank page. and in console its says internal says internal server error. without any descriptive explanation.

Comment: Are you using any PHP framework or core PHP?

Comment: @Alok i am using YII2. but currently i am configuring this in core PHP. because i was found one yii2 extension that is not working properly. its https://github.com/fedemotta/yii2-aws-sdk

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

Comment: @Alok nope i didn't tried that one. i am trying it right now. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116246/discussion-between-albert-akki-and-alok).

Answer (score 0):

Install http://s3tools.org/usage `s3cmd` with either `apt-get` or `yum` and follow directions on here: http://s3tools.org/usage

Within YII you can use php exec or system to get output and results feedback.